# CA1047 'Make member raise private, public, or internal' and C++/CLI events

Tags: c++-cli, fxcop

When I declare a public event in a sealed C++/CLI class, I get Code Analysis warning CA1047.  The warning seems to come from auto-generated protected member functions.  How can I fix this warning?

Here's an example.  This code

```
ref class Test sealed {
public:
    event EventHandler^ blah;
};
```

generates:

> warning: CA1047 : Microsoft.Design : Make member 'Test::blah::raise(Object^, EventArgs^)' private, public, or internal

Comment: Can you show a minimal example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll document the question better.  This code

```
ref class Test sealed {
public:
    event EventHandler^ blah;
};
```

generates:

> warning: CA1047 : Microsoft.Design : Make member 'Test::blah::raise(Object^, EventArgs^)' private, public, or internal

Yes, when you don't specify the event accessors yourself then the compiler will generate them for you.  It auto-generates the add, remove and raise accessors.  The latter one looks like this when you look with ildasm.exe:

```
.method family hidebysig specialname instance void 
        raise_blah(object value0,
                   class [mscorlib]System.EventArgs value1) cil managed
{
    // etc..
}
```

The *family* attribute is what causes the code analysis warning.  The auto-generated add and remove accessors are of course public.  Writing them yourself is a questionable workaround, you really only want to do this if you have a real reason to implement custom accessors.  The boilerplate version would look like this:

```
using namespace System::Runtime::CompilerServices;

ref class Test sealed {
private:
    EventHandler^ foo;
public:
    event EventHandler^ blah {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions::Synchronized)]
        void add(EventHandler^ d) { foo += d; }
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions::Synchronized)]
        void remove(EventHandler^ d) { foo -= d; }
    private:
        void raise(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e) { 
            EventHandler^ handler = foo;
            if (handler != nullptr) handler(sender, e);
        };
    }
};
```

Well, that certainly suppresses the warning.  I recommend you use the [SuppressMessage] attribute if that doesn't spin your propeller.

Comment: Is the `raise` accessor actually needed here?  After all, the backing property can be used directly, or a simple helper function could be used (to provide the race-condition avoidance logic).  Or would the compiler automatically generate a `raise` method if none is explicitly given, and still trigger FxCop?

Comment: Too bad the automatic code generation isn't smart enough to set an appropriate accessor on raise.