# Why can C# not automatically provide thread-safe access to events, where C++/CLI can?

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

From the MSDN documentation for [EventHandler Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx):

> In contrast to the C# and Visual Basic examples, the Visual C++ example
>   code does not require you to create a
>   thread-safe temporary variable. Visual
>   C++ version automatically provides
>   thread-safe access, enabling you to
>   raise the event directly.

Why can C# not automatically provide thread-safe access to events, where C++/CLI can?

Comment: I've updated your question to refer specifically to C++/CLI:  the "Visual C++" name encompasses multiple languages (including C, C++, and C++/CLI), and the language intended in the cited MSDN text is C++/CLI.

Comment: While the question isn't (exactly) subjective and argumentative, I can't quite figure out a way to phrase an answer accurately while avoiding sounding like an outright condemnation of C# as a technical failure.

Comment: @James well, but the MSDN article *does* use the word "Visual C++" to refer to the examples.

Comment: @Yuji: yes, but it's not really accurate -- a conforming implementation of C++ *must* reject the code in the article.

Comment: @Jerry: C# has different priorities, like cool new LINQy stuff and dynamic typing scenarios.  Making thread-safety easy is obviously not a C# priority, just like making deterministic destruction of members easy is not a C# priority.  C++/CLI (and direct access to the Win32 API) tends to solve the problems well that C++ and the Win32 API have always solved well (templates with duck typing, RAII, destructors that implicitly call destructors of members, asynchronous I/O using the overlapped model instead of unnecessary worker threads).

Comment: @Ben: I can't help thinking of LINQ as Microsoft's Maginot Line. Somewhere at Microsoft its designer rubs his hands in glee and proclaims: "LINQ will destroy PowerBuilder once and for all!". Nobody's had the heart to tell him that PowerBuilder was essentially dead and gone before LINQ arrived...

Comment: @Jerry: Right -- I see lots of people using the extension methods, but no one seems to use LINQ syntax.  [And SQL-style syntax has (had) long been available for people who wanted it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_SQL).

Comment: @Jerry: Yes I agree with that. Presumably it serves Microsoft's purpose to use confusing terminology on C++ on Microsoft's websites... Oh my.

Comment: @Yuji: It's nothing new really. For decades vendors (and *not* just MS) have used standards for basically bait and switch tactics. They may preach standardization and portability -- but they do their best to make extensions "compelling" enough to prevent exactly that.

Comment: Besides everything everyone else has already mentioned, if you look at the VB.Net sample, you'll also see no use of a thread-safe temporary variable - the documentation is wrong, VB provides the same thread safety automatically that C++ does.

Comment: @Damien do you mean VB.NET can provide thread safety and not C# in this use case ?

Comment: @user310291 - yes, the VB.Net compiler produces thread-safe code for raising events. From C++, C# and VB, C# is the odd one out in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336790/ca1047-make-member-raise-private-public-or-internal-and-c-cli-events/4339344#4339344) is quite relevant for background info.  An event has three accessors: add, remove and raise.  Respectively to add an event handler, remove it and to raise the event.  The compiler auto-generates one when you don't write an accessor explicitly.

The C++/CLI compiler auto-generates the raise accessor if you don't write one.  It uses the pattern you see in C# code with the helper variable that avoids the null reference exception.  Just as you see it in the linked post.  For some mysterious reason the C# language doesn't do this.  It doesn't even let you define your own accessor, you have to raise the event yourself.  Forcing you to write code with the helper variable.

I have no clue why the C# team made this decision.  As a rule, the team strongly favors avoiding auto-generated code that slows down execution.  The C++ principle of 'you don't pay for what you don't use'.  There are certainly many cases where the thread-safety is unnecessary, any events in GUI code for example.  This is a heck of an edge-case though, given the low cost and the fact that GUI code contains the pattern anyway.  Low-level locking in C++ libraries is however common.

Comment: The "raise" accessor within the event descriptor is vestigial, and is not actually used when raising events.  The fundamental problem in C# is that defining an event `Foo` creates a private field of the same name, rather than e.g. `Foo_event`, and things which should be perceived as operations with an event are instead seen as actions on the delegate.  The language would have been cleaner if `Foo` were an event name, which supported add, remove, invoke-if-not-null, test-against-null, and set-to-null operations, and if doing anything else required explicit reference to the delegate.

Answer (score 1):

While not exactly a duplicate, I believe the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582052/c-event-handlers-not-thread-safe) will help explain why they aren't thread safe in terms of implementation.  Specifically [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582052/c-event-handlers-not-thread-safe/2582595#2582595) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582052/c-event-handlers-not-thread-safe/2582092#2582092) answers.

Marc Gravell's answer:

> IMO, the other answers miss one key
>   detail - that delegates (and therefore
>   events) are immutable. The
>   significance of this is that
>   subscribing or unsubscribing an event
>   handler doesn't simply append/remove
>   to a list - rather, it replaces the
>   list with a new one with an extra (or
>   one less) item on it.
>
> Since references are atomic, this
>   means that at the point you do:
>
> `var handler = SomeEvent;`
>
> you now have
>   a rigid instance that cannot change,
>   even if in the next picosecond another
>   thread unsubscribes (causing the
>   actual event field to become null).
>
> So you test for null and invoke it,
>   and all is well. Note of course that
>   there is still the confusing scenario
>   of the event being raised on an object
>   that thinks it unsubscribed a
>   picosecond ago!