# In C++/CLI how do you define thread-safe event accessors?

Tags: events, thread-safety, c++-cli

The code sample "How to: Define Event Accessor Methods" at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw1dtw0d.aspx

appears to mutate the internal `pE` without taking locks.  (It doesn't look like `Delegate::Combine` does anything magical that would prevent issues.)  It also does

```
void raise() {
   if (pE != nullptr)
      pE->Invoke();
}
```

which can be problematic if `pE` changes to `null` between the check and the `Invoke()`.  I have two questions:

1. Am I right in that the existing code is not thread-safe?
2. Since I want a thread-safe version of the code, I was thinking of locking the `add` and `remove` functions.  Is it premature optimization to use

   ```
   void raise() {
       MyDel^ handler = pE;
       if (handler != nullptr)
          handler->Invoke();
   }
   ```

   or should I just lock that function too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CA1047 'Make member raise private, public, or internal' and C++/CLI events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336790/ca1047-make-member-raise-private-public-or-internal-and-c-cli-events)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[All three accessors are thread-safe by default (`raise` includes a null-check, and uses a local variable to avoid the race condition)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2014752/103167) unlike the example in the page you linked.

When it comes to custom event implementations, you're right about needing to synchronize the `add` and `remove` accessors.  Just put a mutex around the implementation.  But there's no need to throw away type safety by calling `Delegate::Combine` and then casting, [since operator `+` and `-` are overloaded for delegate handles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s23d58wb).  Or you can go lockless, as follows:

```
void add(MyDel^ p)
{
     MyDel^ old;
     MyDel^ new;
     do {
         old = pE;
         new = pE + p;
     } while (old != Interlocked::CompareExchange(pE, new, old));
 }
```

Define `remove` mutatis mutandis (`new = pE - p;`).  And the code you gave for `raise` will be perfectly fine for a custom event implementation.

In summary, that MSDN sample is total garbage.  And the simplest way to achieve thread-safety is with an auto-implemented event.

Comment: Thanks :-)  Just out of curiosity, is there a way for a listener to ensure that its attempt to `remove()` itself has been successful?

Comment: @seeker: The `do`-`while` loop won't exit until it is successfully removed.  Unless you mean whether the listener was even on the subscriber list in the first place, in which case no the event accessors don't provide any way for you to return that information.  But you certainly could make a separate method that checks whether `new.GetInvocationList()->Count != old.GetInvocationList()->Count`

Comment: Yeah, I meant the latter. I was wondering if there might be a problem with `raise()` picking up a really old value of `p`, but I guess the caller to `remove()` has to assume that it can receive an indefinite number of events after `remove()` returns.

Still, it seems like we need to mark `p` as volatile for complete correctness.